# .htaccess how to force www for all kinds of domains in a generic way

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried the following regex to rewrite all requests without a subdomain to be redirected to a www. URL in a generic way as I want this to work for a lot of different domains. If the request contains a subdomain it should be left untouched. No matter if the subdomain is www or something else.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The rule looks for 2 strings separated by a dot which matches for a lot of domains but not the sub-cctlds like .co.uk. So I added another part to the RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)(\.(uk|ar|cy|ar|tr))?$
```

that checks for an optional third dot followed by a range of TLDs that work with sub-ccTLDs.

So this matches

```
domain.com
domain.co.uk
```

but not

```
something.domain.com
something.domain.co.uk
```

OK but unfortunately there are some mixed typed tlds (wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List) like ".es" that allow "domain.es" as well as "domain.com.es". So adding "|es" to the regex would match

```
domain.es
domain.com.es
```

but also

```
www.domain.es
```

which is not wanted here.

Can anyone improve this regex so that it can handle those mixed typed ccTLDs?

Comment: This problem **cannot** be solved perfectly with a regex. Domain names are not "regular" in this sense -- the best you can do is build a long list of white/black-lists for various scenarios. This list is constantly evolving, as defined by the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/).

Comment: However, as a "partial" solution, can you provide a comprehensive list of all the matches + non-matches you wish to cover?

Comment: Also when you say `"So I added another part..."` -- *What* other part? Please include it in your post, so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: thanks, here`s the list of tlds I`d like to cover:

ac
ae
ag
asia
at
be
bg
biz
cc
ch
cn
co.in
co.nz
co.uk
com
com.ar
com.cn
com.cy
com.es
com.tr
com.tw
com.ua
company
cz
de
dk
es
eu
fi
fr
gr
hk
hu
in
info
it
jobs
jp
life
lu
mx
net
nl
no
nrw
org
pe
pl
pt
ro
rs
ru
se
shop
sk
support
tv
tw
ua
uk
us

Comment: > What other part? Please include it in your post, so we can see what the 
> issue is.

just update my post to make it more clear